# match a regular expression with optional lookahead

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have the following strings:

`NAME John Nash FROM California`

`NAME John Nash`

I want a regular expression capable of extracting 'John Nash' for both strings.

Here is what I tried

```
"NAME(.*)(?:FROM)"
"NAME(.*)(?:FROM)?"
"NAME(.*?)(?:FROM)?"
```

but none of these works for both strings.

Comment: Are those both a full line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use logical OR between `FROM` and anchor `$` :

```
NAME(.*)(?:FROM|$)
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/rR3gA0/1

In this case after the name it will match `FROM` or the end of the string.But in your regex since you make the `FROM` optional in firs case it will match the rest of string after the name.

If you want to use a more general regex you better to create your regex based on your name possibility shapes for example if you are sure that your names are create from 2 word you can use following regex :

```
NAME\s(\w+\s\w+)
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/kV2eB9/2

Answer (score 2):

Make the second part of the string optional `(?: FROM.*?)?`, i.e.:

```
NAME (.*?)(?: FROM.*?)?$
```

---

```
MATCH 1
1.  [5-14]  `John Nash`
MATCH 2
1.  [37-46] `John Nash`
MATCH 3
1.  [53-66] `John Doe Nash`
```

---

Regex Demo
https://regex101.com/r/bL7kI2/2

Answer (score 0):

```
 r'^\w+\s+(\w+\s+\w+) - word at start of string
 follows by one or more spaces and
 two words and at least one space between them

with open('data', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
      mo =   re.search(r'^\w+\s+(\w+\s+\w+)',line)
      if mo:
        print(mo.group(1))

John Nash
John Nash
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do without regex:

```
>>> myStr = "NAME John Nash FROM California"
>>> myStr.split("FROM")[0].replace("NAME","").strip()
'John Nash'
```